# External drives won't mount on restart

Tags: macos, hard-drive, usb, mount

One of my staff just got a new Mac mini with the USB 3 ports and Mavericks. It has 2 Seagate GoFlex 3TB hard drives connected: 1 for Time Machine, the other for Dropbox files.

When the computer is restarted, the drives don't mount. They are not visible in Disk Utilities. Unplugging the drives and plugging them back in will mount them. I'd like everything to mount and Dropbox to start up automatically for this user, which worked on the old Mac mini she was using. Now she has to go through multiple steps every time she restarts, which is not ideal.

Any ideas what might be causing this behavior?

Comment: are they a part of spotlight search ?

Comment: These drives have not been added to the privacy tab in Spotlight preferences. I confirmed that files on the Dropbox drive do appear in Spotlight searches. Could this be an issue?

Comment: It could, try it !

Comment: are the drives password protected? Did you look in the Console after restart to see what is going on?

Comment: I added both drives to the Privacy tab of Spotlight preferences and confirmed that files no longer appear in Spotlight searches. Restarted the computer, and no change to the behavior.

Comment: The drives are not password protected. What should I be looking for in Console? I see a bunch of messages like this: "kernel[0]: [0xffffff802b9ae000](2)/(5) Device not responding". There's also this one buried in the middle: "IOUSBMassStorageClass[0xffffff8029d1bc00]: The device is still unresponsive after 6 consecutive USB Device Resets; it will be terminated"

Comment: that's the one ! could you publish the log so to see what is keeping it from doing it. about 30 message should be enough. meanwhile try resetting the SMS

Comment: also just for fun try eject before shutdown-restart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a terminal window and enter the following command:

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/autodiskmount AutomountDisksWithoutUserLogin -bool YES
```

That will prevent macOS X Lion, Mavericks and Yosemite from un-mounting drives at logout. Maybe that's the problem you're seeing as well.

Answer (score 0):

It recently happened to me that my 1TB Seagate drive doesn't show up in diskutil in a iMac and in my Macbook Pro as it used to be.

I noticed that sometimes it doesn't show up on windows notebooks due to inadequate current supply in USB ports.

So my solution is just to replace the USB wire with another one (one comes with a LaCie disk), and every thing got fine.